# Apache alias site needs to load python script with wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a site running with this apache.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin krestensb@gmail.com
    ServerName skovstedconsulting.dk
    ServerAlias www.skovstedconsulting.dk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/skovstedconsulting/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =skovstedconsulting.dk [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.skovstedconsulting.dk
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to serv a python script from the sub path /tdc. So I added this after DocumentRoot:

```
    Alias /tdc /var/www/skovstedconsulting/html/tdc
    WSGIScriptAlias /tdc /var/www/skovstedconsulting/html/tdc/tdc.wsgi
```

The tdc.wsgi looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/skovstedconsulting/html/tdc/")

from TDC import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

All I see visiting /tdc is the content of the directory.

Any help is very appreciated.

Best Regards Kresten

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Alias /tdc /var/www/skovstedconsulting/html/tdc`. You only want the `WSGIScriptAlias`. The `Alias` will override `WSGIScriptAlias`.

See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html

You should also not put the WSGI script file under your existing `DocumentRoot` as people could download your source code.

Comment: It did not change anything.

Comment: Comment out any rewrite rules to verify things work without first.